# How to override the screensaver settings in the MATE desktop:

Tags: screensaver, mate

I installed mate onto Ubuntu 14.04. Before installing mate, I had the Unity and LXDE (Lubuntu Packages) desktop enviroments installed. I installed mate and rebooted. After that, I got two network bars, in LXDE and Unity. I decided to try mate and noticed only one network bar, and I checked the startup applications and disabled the one that didn't have (MATE) at the end, because since the mate one was required for mate, and also worked with Unity and LXDE, why would I need the stock one? The reason I decided to mention this is to explain the picture and get to the point faster with less questions as to why I have two network applets set to start in the picture. I kept the stock one in case I want to uninstall mate, which I most likely won't do. So, my question is, what do I need to disable to prevent the computer from going to sleep? I use an INSIGNIA HDTV I recently purchased near June or July, and if the PC goes to sleep, the TV says "No Signal" and then turns off after about 5 minutes? So, I have to use a remote to power it on, as if I move the mouse while the TV screen is off, nothing happens. I'm assuming the power manager does this, but I don't know what would happen if I turned it off. My PC is also hooked to my TV standard? (Not sure what you call it, but it isn't! DVI or HDMI) Any help?
[image]
Other things hooked to the TV:
Nintendo Wii (and a shiny new PS4 I got for Christmas)

(No TV signal is hooked to the TV at this moment.)

Also, I couldn't find this setting in the MATE desktop, but here's a screenshot of System Settings> Brightness & Lock.

Also, sorry about this but I forgot to add that this only happens in the MATE desktop, not the other two desktops.

[image]

Comment: Actual single strength  strength will not change because your using Mate, Unity or Gnome. Single strength can change with objects that have moved, and placement or WIFI router and your WIFI device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two settings you can work with:

- System Settings -> Brightness & Lock -> Turn screen off when inactive for
- System Settings -> Power -> Suspend when inactive for

The first will signal the display to turn itself off, the second will put the computer into a sleep state. I'm assuming you're referring to the first behavior.

That being said, remember that TVs don't behave the same way that monitors do. A monitor will go to sleep ("suspend") and wake up when instructed to, but most TVs don't implement suspend mode: they will display a "No Signal" message for a few minutes and then turn off.

You'll need a computer monitor if you want display suspend functionality.

Comment: It was set to never, and it looks like I forgot to mention that this only happens in MATE, not Unity or LXDE. What's even better is that I had another Samsung TV I used to use, but it broke down. It appears to be working normally, but when pressing the button it used to take about 5 seconds to boot, but now it's stuck in the boot process for HOURS, while the TV's shutdown is normal. when the PC was shut off when hooked to that, it did just what a monitor was supposed to, display no signal then turn off the display. Also, the PC is hooked via a standard VGA (or is it PCI?) cable.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:**

I installed Mate from tasksel onto Ubuntu server. Consequently, it is the only window manager installed without additional features from Gnome or Unity installed.

---

**Power management in Mate on Ubuntu:**

> Power management is what you need to adjust to prevent your computer
>   from going to sleep.
>
> - On the menu bar, select system.
> - Then select control center.
> - Then in the hardware section, select screen saver.
>
> [image: screenshot]

---

**Screen saver settings in Mate on Ubuntu:**

> Another point of interest is the screen saver.
>
> - On the menu bar, select system.
> - Then select control center.
> - In the personal section. select screen saver.
>
> [image: Screen Shot]

---

**Additional notes:**

> 1. When Mate is the only window manager installed, Brightness and lock is not available and I am not sure it would even work in Mate.
> 2. Many TVs will turn off to save power when it is not receiving a signal. This may or may not be adjustable on your TV, but it probably
>      does not need to be adjusted after configuring power management and
>      screen saver settings for Mate on Ubuntu.
> 3. Screen-shots and instructions were performed on Ubuntu 15.10. If a procedure differs for other releases please add your comment so that I
>      can add an update.